# How to customizing alignment to components inside a Row on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm building a `Card` to show a image and some text information. I want that RED Container content align to top and not the center like current. I'm using a `Row` to divide the `Image` and `Texts` contents. Besides that I want change the position of `Texts` on whole space at the right of image, so how I can manage it?

Card Widget

```
  Widget buildExerciseCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 0),
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                exerciseList[index].imagePath,
                width: 75,
                height: 75,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(exerciseList[index].name),
                    Text(exerciseList[index].bodyPart),
                    Text(exerciseList[index].muscle)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  Widget buildExerciseCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 0),
      child: Card(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Image.asset(
                exerciseList[index].imagePath,
                width: 75,
                height: 75,
                fit: BoxFit.contain,
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(exerciseList[index].name),
                    Text(exerciseList[index].bodyPart),
                    Text(exerciseList[index].muscle)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

Comment: This just expand the Container/Column to all horizontal space, and not align with top.

Comment: Check Now. I have updated the code. It's working as you're expecting